Ramification vs Repercussion. Can a "ramification" be positive?
I'm trying to differentiate ramification and repercussion. According to CD, it seems that ramification is more neutral, while repercussion is mostly negative. In other words, ramification ~ effect and repercussion ~ consequence.
However, I found examples of "negative ramifications", but none of "positive ramifications". Why is that so? Does that mean "ramification" is also usually negative?

I think you're interpreting things correctly.
By default, both ramification and repercussion have a negative connotation. If you want to use ramification in a positive sense, you will probably have to call it a positive ramification, because by default it is considered negative.
Repercussions are pretty much always negative. You don't typically have positive repercussions, although there's probably no hard rule against it.
An even more neutral word is outcome. Outcomes can be either positive or negative, and there's not really a default implied connotation.
